# Get list of objects as response Web client Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, get, spring-webclient

I have a spring boot application that will send requests to another using "WebClient". I am using java 20 and spring boot 3.0. I am a noob in spring boot, I am trying my best.

This is the model class:

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Interface {
        public String interface_name;
        public String network;
    }
```

This is the class that will make the request:

```
   @Service
public class Get_Interfaces_Service {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    private String url="http://";

    public Get_Interfaces_Service(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }
 public List<Interface> get_Interfaces_Service_Method(String minion_name){

        Minion minion = Syncronized_Mininos.getMinion(minion_name);


        if(minion == null){
            return null;
        }


        String url_for_interfaces = this.url +
                minion.ip_address +
                ":" +
                minion.port
                +"/minion/getInterfaces";

        URI uri = UriComponentsBuilder
                .fromHttpUrl(url_for_interfaces)
                .build(Collections
                        .emptyMap());


        return this.webClient
                .get()
                .uri(uri)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Interface.class)
                .block();
    }
```

The other application is working perfectly:

This is the second model:

```
@Data
public class Interface {

    public String interface_name;
    public String network;

    public Interface(String interface_name,
                     String network){
        this.interface_name = interface_name;
        this.network = network;
    }
}
```

This is the class that returns the list:

```
static List<Interface> interfaces;
.....
public static synchronized List<Interface> get_synchronized_interfaces_method() {
    return interfaces;
}
```

The output using postman of the second application is:

```
[
    {
        "interface_name": "default",
        "network": "10.33.16.1"
    },
    {
        "interface_name": "10.33.16.0/24",
        "network": "wlp3s0"
    },
    {
        "interface_name": "169.254.0.0/16",
        "network": "virbr0"
    },....
```

And this is the output of the first application when is requesting the list:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [collection type; class com.Master_Hacking_Node.Master_Node.indexes.model.Interface, contains [recursive type; com.Master_Hacking_Node.Master_Node.indexes.model.Interface]\n\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:271)\n\tSuppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below: \nError has been observed at the following site(s):\n\t*__checkpoint ⇢ Body from GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/minion/getInterfaces [DefaultClientResponse]\nOriginal Stack Trace:\n\t\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.processException(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:271)\n\t\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.decode(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:211)\n\t\tat org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.lambda$decodeToMono$2(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:191)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:132)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.Operators$BaseFluxToMonoOperator.completePossiblyEmpty(Operators.java:2071)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:145)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:350)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:371)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:724)\n\t\tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFlattenIterable.java:273)\n\t\tat reactor.adapter.JdkFlowAdapter$SubscriberToRS.onComplete(JdkFlowAdapter.java:160)\n\t\tat java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$PublishingBodySubscriber.complete(ResponseSubscribers.java:939)\n\t\tat java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$PublishingBodySubscriber.lambda$new$1(ResponseSubscribers.java:870)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptNow(CompletableFuture.java:757)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniAcceptStage(CompletableFuture.java:735)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.thenAccept(CompletableFuture.java:2214)\n\t\tat java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.ResponseSubscribers$PublishingBodySubscriber.lambda$new$2(ResponseSubscribers.java:870)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:863)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:841)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)\n\t\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2179)\n\t\tat java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.
```

Do you have any idea what should I do in this situation?

Comment: You can replace bodyToMono with bodyToFlux method , which itself represent the unbound stream of elements and easily converts from Json array response

Comment: @Irremediable hello! I already tried and it did not work, if you can provide an example I would much appreciate it.

Comment: Try bodyToFlux(..).collectList().block()

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return a `List` of `Interface` objects.

```java
return this.webClient
    .get()
    .uri(uri)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(Interface.class)
    .collectList()
    .block();
```

`bodyToFlux` will create a `Flux` to handle the `Interface` objects in the response. Since you don't want to process them once at a time, but want a `List` containing all of them you need to call `collectList()` on the `Flux`. The result of that call is a `Mono<List<Interface>>`. That `Mono` can be handled the way you did in your code using the `block` method.

Comment: Thank you so much! But in my case is still not working, I have tried this before I posted the question. Now I tried again and I receive this error: "Cannot construct instance of `com.Master_Hacking_Node.Master_Node.indexes.model.Interface` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator) at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]"

Comment: Ok, the thing is that the underlaying JSON library needs to know how to construct the Java Object. You have two options.
1. You add a default constructor (a constructor without parameters). The library will use that to create the instance and then call the setters to set the values.

2. You keep the constructor you have right now, but tell the library how to use your constructor. You can do that using the `@JsonProperty` annotation.
`public Interface(@JsonProperty("interface_name") String interface_name, @JsonProperty("network") String network)`

Comment: If you use the `@JsonProperty` annotation you can also change the name of interface_name to interfaceName (Java style). The parameter of the `@JsonProperty` annotation matches the JSON property. `public Interface(@JsonProperty("interface_name") String interfaceName, @JsonProperty("network") String network)`